# SFMC SQL How to select 1 record

Tags: salesforce, soql, salesforce-marketing-cloud

Customers Data extension

| Customer_ID |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 5 |
| 6 |

Orders data extension

| Customer_ID | Shipment_Type |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 1 | A |
| 3 | C |
| 1 | B |
| 5 | E |

I would like to see the following result by picking only first record of shipment type from A, C, E

| Customer_ID | Shipment_Type |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 3 | C |
| 5 | E |

I tried the following but it is showing me all the results combining both Data extensions

SELECT t1.customer_id, t2.Shipment_Type
FROM Customers t1
Inner Join Orders t2
ON t1.customer_id = t2.customer_id
Where t2.Shipment_Type IN ('A','C','E)

Comment: Simply `SELECT DISTINCT`? (And skip the JOIN.)

Comment: DISTINCT will not work because on target data extension I am combining Customers ID and Shipment Type. If it is only 1 record then Distinct would have worked.

Comment: There is no way of establishing first from the published data.

Comment: Using `SELECT DISTINCT`: https://dbfiddle.uk/LRGKp7fc